# Three series convergence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Having that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is a convergent series and we know that $a_n > 0$ can we say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \sin(a_n)$ also converges?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm not sure if I can use something like comparision for the series that $-a_n<a_n \sin(a_n) < a_n$ but I tried only this method

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it converges, by the comparison test and because$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\bigl\lvert a_n\sin(a_n)\bigr\rvert\leqslant\lvert a_n\rvert=a_n.$$

Comment: +1..Forgot about this.

Comment: Note that, since $\sum a_n$ is convergent, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Since $a_n>0$, this implies that $a_n\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ for $n$ large enough, so $\sin(a_n)>0$ for $n$ large enough. Therefore, you don't need the absolute value. (Of course, it makes the proof longer...)

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sum a_n$ converges, for each $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N^*$ s.t. whenever $\mathbb N^* \ni n > N, p \in \mathbb N^*$, $\sum_{n+1}^{n+p} a_k < \varepsilon$. Then 
$$
\left\vert \sum_{n+1}^{n+p} a_k \sin (a_k) \right\vert \leqslant \sum_{n+1}^{n+p} \vert a_k \sin (a_k ) \vert \leqslant \sum_{n+1}^{n+p} a_k < \varepsilon, 
$$
hence $\sum a_n \sin(a_n)$ converges by Cauchy convergence principle.